# How To Change VS Code Color Picker Settings

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, color-picker

Here is the problem: I have a color `Color(0xFF393F4C)` in code, now I change it in VS Code and it automatically makes it into this format `Color.fromARGB(255, 87, 109, 151)`. How to make the first option the default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the Circle with half white and half black on the top left corner, it will change the type.

[image: vs code color picker for flutter]

Comment: Yes, this is what I showed in the gif image and it changes the format of the selected color. But if I start changing the color again, then it will again do ARGB, and I need it to do it in hex by default, and not in ARGB